# Issue with union member initialization

Tags: c, unions

I am trying below code:

```
typedef union Data
{
   int i;
}data;

int main( )
{
   data d1;     
   d1.i = 10; // OK
   data d3 = {7};// OK
   data d2.i = 20; // Gives error
}
```

My question why it is giving error for `data d2.i = 20` and works for other?

Comment: `data d1 = {7};// OK` should already give an error because you are redefining `d1`.

Comment: The last line declares the variable `d2`, whereas for the previous initialisation lines, the variable `d1` has already been declared. the line `d1 = {7}` uses a particular type of definition (an initialiser list) where the `{}` say "put this in the members in the order listed", the last line does not have this so you are trying to declare a data type variable named `d2.i` and give the entire object a value of 20.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it's not valid syntax.

It has nothing to do with the `union`, i.e. it would be the same for a `struct`.

You're trying to use the name of a `union` member as a name, that's not valid. Names cannot contain the dot (`.`).

The initializations work since there is a matching (sort of) of the initializer expression (the right-hand side) to the type of the left hand side, but that's not what you're trying in the last line.

I think this would work, and sort of be close:

```
data d2 = { .i = 20 };
```

This uses C99 syntax to name the target member inside the initializer list.